# Proving a limit exists for the next multi-variable function:$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Proving a limit exists for the next multi-variable  function: $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$.

I know it's pretty much the basics, But i do not undetstand how to prove whether a limit exists.

What i did so far was:
Let $x=r\cos\alpha$ and $y=r\sin\alpha$.
I'll prove $\lim_{r\to0} f(r)=f(r)$

So i'll get $\lim_{r\to0}r\frac {\cos^3\alpha+\sin^3\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}=\lim_{r\to0}r\frac {\cos^3\alpha+\sin^3\alpha}{1}=0 $

Is the above enough for proving limit exists? Overall, What are the different ways of proving a limit of a two variable exists?

Comment: Which is the "original" limit for $f(x,y)?$ Is it $(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$? In this case I would even use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, with the norm in $\mathbb R^2$ in the $\delta$-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's enough. Converting to polar coordinates is usually the easiest or most efficient way to prove existence of a limit. Other methods including using the formal $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition or the Squeeze Theorem.

To prove that a limit does NOT exist, one easy method is to pick two different paths that approach the given point that result in different limits.

Comment: Thank you. Been needing that confirmation for self-confidence.